# Service variable not being watched

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, ng-show

I have a service as thus

```
function() {
    this.show = false;

    this.toggle = function() {
        this.show = !this.show;
    }
}
```

and the menu has an ng-show looking at MenuService.show

this works perfectly, however I am trying make it so that when user clicks within the main page it sets show to false, thus, hiding the menu. I have this code

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("pages")).bind("click", function() {
    $scope.menuService.show = false;
});
```

but the ng-show doesnt seem to be taking any notice of show now being false and continues to show. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are binding to events (using `bind`) outside of Angular, then you need to `$apply` to run an Angular digest and update the scope:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("pages")).bind("click", function() {
    $scope.menuService.show = false;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: just testing this now, as i am relatively new to angular if i did $scope.$on.... would i need to put the apply in too? or would it not work at all? (not tested for syntax errors etc, at all atm